# Jstree save tree to xml file after drag and drop

Tags: javascript, xml, asp.net-mvc-3

using jstree plugin I input the tree data from an xml file. I need to save the xml data after drag and drop operation on a button click.
The data.inst.get_xml("nest", -1, li_attr, a_attr) event gives the current  xml. How do I save this to an xml file in MVC 3 view

This is the javascript used to render the tree-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    li_attr = ["id", "class"];

    a_attr = ["href"];

    $("#Sampletree").jstree({

        "xml_data": {
            "ajax": {
                "url": "../../Content/Files/Sample.xml"
            },
            "xsl": "nest"
        },
        "plugins": ["themes", "xml_data", "dnd", "ui"
    },

    {
        "dnd": {
            "drop_finish": function () {
                alert("DROP");
            },
            "drag_check": function (data) {
                if (data.r.attr("id") == "phtml_1") {
                    return false;
                }
                return {
                    after: false,
                    before: false,
                    inside: true
                };
            },
            "drag_finish": function (data) {
                alert("DRAG OK");
            }
        }

    })

    .bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
        alert(data.inst.get_xml("nest", -1, li_attr, a_attr)

    });


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **data.inst.get_xml("nest", -1, li_attr, a_attr)** event gives the current xml as a string. Set this as a hidden input field. This hidden field value can be received while submitting the form. The rest can take care by the controller.

Cheers,
Princi